# Why would the headers from a framework not be accessible?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion

I'm trying to port my C++ application to OSX using CLion.  It makes use of SDL2 and SDL2_Mixer.

I include both of them through use of Find.cmake by this in my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

if (${SDL2_FOUND})
    message("SLD2 found")
    message(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

find_package(SDL2_mixer REQUIRED)

if (${SDL2_mixer_FOUND})
    message("SDL2_Mixer found")
    message(${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

That gives me this output in my CMake log

```
SLD2 found
/Users/saurbaum/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
SDL2_Mixer found
/Users/saurbaum/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework/Headers
```

Which all appears to have worked correctly.  When I try and include the headers for SDL and its extensions it fails to compile.

For example

```
 fatal error: 'SDL_mixer.h' file not found #include <SDL_mixer.h>
```

I've tried with

```
#include "SDL2/SDL_mixer.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"
```

and just in case there was some difference in this compiler.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
```

Same code works nicely on Windows and Linux just OSX that's giving me the headache.